# SharePoint 2013 & Crawling File Shares

Tags: search, enterprise-search

Does anyone have any information they can direct me to on how SharePoint performs incremental/full crawls on file shares.  We have a large file share we are indexing 2TB and I would like to know is incremental crawl really just a full crawl because how would SharePoint know if data was changed/deleted/added?  Sharepoints incremental crawls are faster then full crawls by a few hours but I dont understand how SP is then tracking File Share changes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, the crawler looks at new, updated and deleted content during an incremental crawl. It is faster for a few reasons. The obvious is because there should be less content. Less obvious is that during incremental crawls new properties are not processed. For new properties you need to perform a full crawl periodically.